# Pass parameters from C# into Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery

How do you pass a parameter from C# into the **value** part of    instead of hard coding it with different values.

```
<div class="property-container">
      <input class="progress-value" type="hidden" value="17" />           
        <div class="property-title">Test</div> 
        <div class="property-progress"></div>
    </div>    

    <div class="property-container">
        <input class="progress-value" type="hidden" value="32" />
        <div class="property-title">Test 2</div> 
        <div class="property-progress"></div>
    </div>    

    <div class="property-container">
        <input class="progress-value" type="hidden" value="24" />
        <div class="property-title">Test 3</div> 
        <div class="property-progress"></div>
    </div>    

        <script type="text/javascript" >/
            $(function () {
                // loop through each 'container'
                $(".property-container").each(function () {


                    // get the value that was rendered from the model
                    var progress = parseInt($(this).children(".progress-value").val());

                    // create the progress bar with the value
                    $(this).children(".property-progress").progressbar({ value: progress });

                });
            });

        </script>
```

Comment: Where do you want the value? Can you not just call a method like `<%=GetValue()%>`

Comment: <input class="progress-value" type="hidden" value="17" id="Test" /> In c# I tried, Test.Value = "20"; but its not working

Comment: Are you using webforms? mvc?

Comment: Is this a real time progress bar?

Comment: No. I am eventually going to put it in an update panel. But the data comes from the server.

Comment: UpdatePanel might be overkill here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments

```
<input class="progress-value" type="hidden" value="17" id="Test" /> 
In c# I tried, Test.Value = "20";
```

You should have a `runat="server"` if you want to access the hidden field in your codebehind.

```
<input class="progress-value" runat="server" type="hidden" value="17" id="Test" /> 

 //& then in C# set it like this..

 Test.Value = "20";
```

In jQuery, get the value of the hidden field

```
$('.progress-value').val()
```

Comment: Do you know what is a proper way to refresh this progress bar every few seconds. Like I said I am getting dynamic data from a C# string.

Comment: you can use jQuery Ajax for it, UpdatePanel is one way. Depending on your requirement & complexity.. but thats a whole another topic.

Comment: Instead of solving the problem you went to a different ( less better) approach.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - thanks for the comment.. please look at what OP has tried in the comments section. I explained him where he went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this :

```
 $(this).children(".property-progress").progressbar({ value: '<%= MyValue() %>'});
```

And in the `c#` create a `property`:

```
Public string MyValue
{
  get;set;
}
```

**Nb**

If you intend to update the progressbar according to server activity - i'd suggest you to google signalR.

Comment: public string MyValue
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            MyValue = "25";
        }

Comment: @Apollo You set a value in the server "25" , and then you need to see the progress bar at "25%"...right ?

Comment: try `value: <%= MyValue() %>` ( no `'`)

Comment: I get this. The name 'MyValue' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Apollo it is the aspx of the page...right ? so it should know it.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remember where the variables are set, and where the code is run.  C# runs on the server, so you can't set javascript properties directly, rather, you need to set up your HTML template so that when it is interpolated by the server the correct values are sent to the client.

In other words, you won't be able to set the progress bar width on the server, b/c the server will only be able to set the initial value of the progress bar.  It will be up to the client to increment the value.  Otherwise, you'd need to constantly be posting the page back to the server, which isn't what you want at all.

The easiest way to get the progress data from the server to the client is by setting up a web service that returns JSON, and calling it using jquery.

Here are some resources on how to do that:

- [Create and Call a Simple Web Service in ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-and-call-a-simple-web-service-in-aspnet)
- [Understanding ASP.NET AJAX Web Services](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services)
- [ASP.net progress bar updated via jQuery ajax during async operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886241/asp-net-progress-bar-updated-via-jquery-ajax-during-async-operation)

You should be able to decorate a method on your asp.net class with [WebMethod] to make it callable via jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what technology you're using to output code.  If you're using Razor, it would be:

```
<input value="@ObjectName.Value">
```